# Open SwiftUI App from other application, Microsoft Teams, Messenger, WhatsApp, etc

Tags: ios, swift, url, mobile, swiftui

I am developing an SwiftUI App that app involves with creating notes like an usual to-do list app. The exception is that the note must be able to be shared to another users via Microsoft Teams, Messengers and WhatsApp.

Thus, I tend to implement some sort of functionalities to send another user one URL link. Every time the users click on the link from third-party app (WhatsApp, Teams, FB), the link will prompt and navigate users to the app that I developed and installed on their machine. Based on the URL my app will perform specific actions.

How I can do that. My current attempt is to define a customer URL for the SwiftUI app.

Thanks for reading this question, cheers.

Comment: Check for "universal linking" and "deep linking". Choose one which suits you. Deep linking is easy to integrate.

Comment: hello, I tried to do the same thing but the URL Scheme link only works when I type the link on Safari web browser. If I send the link as text through another app, the link is not clickable

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Custom URL Scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app) and [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/)

From documentation:

> Custom URL schemes provide a way to reference resources inside your app. Users tapping a custom URL in an email, for example, launch your app in a specified context. Other apps can also trigger your app to launch with specific context data; for example, a photo library app might display a specified image.

```swift
let url = URL(string: "myphotoapp:Vacation?index=1")
       
UIApplication.shared.open(url!) { (result) in
    if result {
       // The URL was delivered successfully!
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, I tried to do the same thing but the URL Scheme link only works when I type the link on Safari web browser. If I send the link as text through another app, the link is not clickable

Comment: hi! did you manage to solve your problem? this URL should be valid for any app.